# php mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hey, I have a quick one. Is there any way to include a variable into a prepared query? example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, author, LEFT(description, 40) AS excerpt, 
               image_small, image_med, date 
        FROM posts 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT $start, $postsPerPage";

$result = $connect->prepare($sql) or die ('error');
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($id, $title, $author, $excerpt, $image_small, $image_med, $date);
```

Thanks!

Comment: your question is incomplete, i think what you wanted to ask is: how can i retrieve the results from a prepared query. your result variables will be empty until you call `$result->fetch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want the following:

```
$start = 1; $postsPerPage = 1;
$sql = "SELECT id, title, author, LEFT(description, 40) AS excerpt, 
               image_small, image_med, date 
        FROM posts 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT ?, ?";

$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql) or die ('error');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $start, $postsPerPage);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $author, $excerpt, $image_small, $image_med, $date);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
  printf('<h1>%s</h1><p>%s <small> by %s on %s</small></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($title),
    htmlspecialchars($excerpt),
    htmlspecialchars($author),
    htmlspecialchars($date)
  );
}
```

this binds both question marks to integer (`i`) values of `$start` and `$postsPerPage`. do **NOT** use variables directly in prepared statements, because that would defeat the whole purpose of prepared statements (apart from eliminating parsing time)

Comment: Huh, see this is exactly what I wrote, same order and everything. The variables get declared before all of this so I cant figure out why its not displaying..

Comment: @tim: no it's not the same. you insert your variables directly into your sql string (no escaping is happening!). your question is probably misleading, i guess you miss `$result->fetch()` after that

Comment: I guess I am confused then. At what point am I supposed to assign values to these bound variables?

Comment: you are not supposed to assign values to them. `$result->fetch()` sets them accordingly to your query. `$start` and `$postsPerPage` have obviously to be set before calling `$result->execute()`. try my code, it should print a list of your db content

Comment: Ah, see what I was trying to do was set my limit based on variables I already have.. They come from another query which sets the amount of listings based on a settings stored in another table. Is there no way to pass variables through that query then?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

on this page they seem to do exactly what I am trying to do. Set the variables afterwords. Its just not working for me.

Comment: @tim: see that line: `$result->bind_param('ii', $start, $postsPerPage);`, right there? that binds both variables to the question marks in the query (`?`), like described in my answer. where's the problem? what output do you expect, and what actual output do you get? have you tried my code?

Comment: Correct.. it binds those variables to the query. I get that. However what I dont get, is why it does not USE the values i have stated for those variables. For instance. $start = 0, and $postsPerPage = 3, however this does not work, and I get a blank query because I think it defaults to 0, 0. Does this make more sense? I actually want to USE the values I have stated for the variables.

Comment: i don't think that. there must be an error somewhere else. try turning on all errors (`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE)`) and see if it gives you any hints. is there data in your db? are you querying the correct table?

Comment: '$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $postsPerPage");' This is my old query which worked just fine. I really just replaced it more or less. The problem seems to be that it does not like my variables not being an absolute value. for instance, if I state '$start=0' it works, but if I do '$start=($pageRequest * $postsPerPage) - $postsPerPage;' it does not work. :(

Comment: It also does not let me do $postsPerPage = $settings->postsPerList; 

which would tell it to equal the value from another query I am doing.

Comment: `LIMIT $start, $postsPerPage` is *not* how you do it. that's a first class sql injection spot. something must be wrong with your calculation. print (i.e. `var_dump($start)`) your variables before executing the query (and maybe even after running it). are the values what you expect?

Comment: also, reading your calculation again, didn't you mean `$start = ($pageRequest * $postsPerPage) - 1`?? instead of `- $postsPerPage`? your calculation always wrong by $postsPerPage pages – which in turn gives negative vaulues for all $start < $postsPerPage

Comment: @tim: what does `var_dump($settings->postsPerList)` give you? is your previous query executed *and then* rows get **fetched**? otherwise your variable will not be set (still has the old value)

Comment: There is more calculations going on above all of this. its all based on some get values of the pagination which leads you to this page. Anyways. Im really confused now, because it looks like my other query no longer works since doing this prepare statement. $settings = Posts::settingsQuery();

That is a class I made which just does the query. So I set it back to:

$settings_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");
$settings = mysql_fetch_array($settings_query);

yet I am still getting NULL values

Comment: as i said: do poor man's debugging (`var_dump()`) and make sure you actually query the correct db and that there are records in that table. if it's ‘not working at all’ then i'm afraid i can't help you, even if i tried

Comment: aka. If the pageRequest = 3, and postsPerPage = 4, 3*4=12, and 12-4 = 8. So I start my query at 8 if I am on page 3, since page 1 and 2 were 0-7

Comment: You have helped me a bunch. I really appreciate it. I need to start learning some debugging methods as I am still new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

- Use question marks as placeholders in the SQL where you want the value of the variable to be.
- Use [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind values to the placeholders.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken you have to use bindParam and replace the variables in your query with a question mark

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, author, LEFT(description, 40) AS excerpt, 
               image_small, image_med, date 
        FROM posts 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT ?, ?";

$result = $connect->prepare($sql) or die ('error');
$result->bindParam(1, $start);
$result->bindParam(2, $postsPerPage);
```

you can find more examples at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php