# Mysqli prepared statement working in SQL but not in my application

Tags: php, mysql, web, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent date out of my DB with this:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT reportDate FROM reports WHERE bot=? ORDER BY reportDate DESC LIMIT ?");
$limit = 1;
$stmt2->bind_param("ii", $id, $limit);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($lastSeen);
```

I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I know this usually happens when there's a syntax error in the SQL statement, but I've tried running it in phpmyadmin and it works like a charm. Any suggestion?

Comment: I dont think you can set the limit placeholder it has to be static value.

Comment: You have not defined `$id`? But the error here means that `$stmt2` is not an object when you call `bind_param()`.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention that $id is a variable that i'm fetching with while($stmt->fetch()) through another query (which works normally)

Comment: don't try to guess what caused the error, turn on error reporting then, `$conn->prepare("query here") or die($conn->error);`. anyway, binding limit offset seems to be accepted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375182/php-mysqli-prepared-statement

Answer (score 2):

**LIMIT** does not take any parameters from prepared statements ordinarily, hence your `prepare` fails. And that is why you see that error on the next call.

Also go through [How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-bindvalue-in-limit) and [LIMIT keyword on MySQL with prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 1):

`$stmt2` is not an object, try to `var_dump()` it.

Comment: This is what i get when i var_dump($stmt2): object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(2) }

Comment: `$stmt2->bind_param("ii", $id, $limit);` What's `ii` ? You should read the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Oh sorry, I use PDO the most of the time and I forget the title of your question. :)
So you don't have the Fatal error anymore no ?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this query, but i've come to think that the problem might be related to the fact that i'm using multiple nested prepared statements. I've been trying with other queries and the result is the same :/

Comment: Hum, maybe your problem is you are using the same variables names?